# How to return (not print) a fraction in python without simplifying it?

Tags: python

The code below **prints** simplified fraction. But I want a non simplified one. Ex: If the answer is 2/4 I want the code to **return** 2/4 not 1/2.

```
from fractions import Fraction
def frac(n,d):
    print(Fraction(n/d))
```

frac(2,4) gives 1/2.

```
from fractions import Fraction
def frac(n,d):
    return(Fraction(n/d))
```

`frac(2/4)` gives `Fraction(1,2)`

What I want is return (`Fraction(n/d)`) to give `2/4`.

How do I achieve this in python?

Comment: Create your own class?

Comment: Why does it matter to you? Objectively, `2/4 === 1/2`. If you need the original values, keep track of them in a separate data structure or subclass `Fraction` to do so for you.

Comment: `fractions.Fraction` represents rational numbers, not a numerator and a denominator. It's like how `int` doesn't represent leading zeros, because it represents an integer, not a sequence of digits.

Comment: Also never do `Fraction(n/d)`. That does float arithmetic. Use `Fraction(n, d)`.

Comment: Several people have posted answers using the undocumented `_normalize` parameter now. Don't use that. It's not intended for public use, and stuff will **actually break** if you try it, ranging from wrong math results to spurious ZeroDivisionErrors. [Here's a wrong math result example](https://ideone.com/kUiIDg), and [here's a spurious exception example](https://ideone.com/fSTLMb).

Answer (score 1):

First, let's understand what is happening here, then we'll have a look at how to change it.

You have two different questions/problems in this one question.

**Part 1: How to get "1/2" instead of "Fraction(1,2)"**

When you print a fraction, it is first cast to string, and that returns the kind of output you want. If you just output the Fraction on the console (what is what happens when you call the function from the REPL), it is instead converted to string using `repr()`

```
str(Fraction(2/4)) --> "1/2"
repr(Fraction(2/4)) --> "Fraction(1, 2)"
```

So first, if you want to return the Fraction as a string, before the `return` you need to cast it to string:

```
def frac(n,d):
    return str(Fraction(n/d))
```

**Part 2: Don't normalize the fraction**

You said, you want to have `frac(2,4)` return `"2/4"` and not `"1/2"`.
Let's see what happens in your code:

```
Fraction(n/d)
```

Since you pass `n/d` as a parameter to `Fraction()`, the division will be executed first, before the value even goes to `Fraction()`. To make this point more clear, let's execute the code statement by statement:

```
n=2
d=4
2/4 -> 0.5
Fraction(0.5)
```

As you see, you pass the divided result to `Fraction()`, so there is no way for `Fraction()` to know the divisor.

But, even passing the numerator and the divisor as separate parameters won't help you, since Fraction represents a normalized fraction.

That's just how that class works.

Answer (score -1):

You can return a tuple from Fraction's numerator and denominator like (n, d) or as a string '1/2'. There is no other way

Answer (score -1):

Creating a class and suitable functions might work.

```
class frac():
    def __init__(self,num,den):
        self.num = num
        self.den = den
    def decimal(self):
        return self.num / self.den
```

Something along the lines of that.